# Why can boxed integer value get implicitly converted to string type?

Tags: c#

I thought class can be implicitly converted only to:

- any class in the chain from which it is derived
- any interface that it implements

a) None of the above is true in next example, so why does boxed integer value get implicitly converted to `string` type:

```
string s = 100 + “question”;
```

b) Why then doesn’t the value in next assignment also get implicitly converted to `string` type:

```
string s = 100;
```

thanx

Comment: Incidentally, your bullet list omits a number of items. You have omitted identity conversions, covariant and contravariant interface conversions, user-defined implicit conversions, and conversions to the dynamic type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just the string concatenation operator - nothing to do with boxing or integers in particular... it's *any* value which is being concatenated with a string.

Your second example doesn't involve any concatenation, hence no conversion.

From the C# spec, section 7.8.4:

> For an operation of the form x + y,
>   binary operator overload resolution
>   (§7.3.4) is applied to select a
>   specific operator implementation. The
>   operands are converted to the
>   parameter types of the selected
>   operator, and the type of the result
>   is the return type of the operator.
>
> The predefined addition operators are
>   listed below. For numeric and
>   enumeration types, the predefined
>   addition operators compute the sum of
>   the two operands. When one or both
>   operands are of type string, the
>   predefined addition operators
>   concatenate the string representation
>   of the operands.

and then:

> String concatenation:
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation.
>   If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted.
>   Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation
>   by invoking the virtual ToString method inherited from type object.
>   If `ToString` returns null, an empty string is substituted.

In fact, in your example, with the current MS C# compiler, it will simply box the integer and call `string.Concat(object, object)` - but the compiler knows that will have the same result as calling `string.Concat(100.ToString(), "question")`.

One interesting point of fact: the + operator doesn't exist in the `string` class itself. The language has special handling for it (as we've already seen) which ends up calling `Concat`. One advantage of this is that

```
x + y + z
```

can be compiled into

```
string.Concat(x, y, z)
```

which can perform the whole concatenation in one go, rather than building a pointless intermediate string.

(Also, note that the compiler performs concatenations of compile-time constant strings itself.)

Comment: Damn it Skeet! 16 seconds faster.  I'm never gonna catch you in the C# tag at this rate.

Comment: @Alio, @Justin: the trick is to very quickly post a half-baked answer.  You then got 5 minutes to edit the answer, nobody can see that you did.  Other than a sometimes very confused OP.  That also works to get the quick lazy upvote and get more votes when you finish your real answer.  Being on top of the list draws lots of votes.

Comment: @Hans: Agreed, although the "half-baked" answer needs to be at least somewhat useful and accurate. I would never post a random string of words just to "bag" the first spot, for example.

Comment: Right, that would be an "un-baked" answer.  Good for efficiently attracting downvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of the + operator and not the boxing.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the `+` operator.

Essentially, the method signature for `+` in this case is:

```
public string +(string s) {
    return this.ToString() + s;
}
```

So, the `int` gets converted to a `string`.

But, it is simply a syntax error to try and stick an `int` value into a `string` reference.